# Permissions not working with Tabs menus?

Tags: 7, routes, users

I have Menus with Tab structure Working from my custom module. But When I built permissions for each Tab It does not work according to assigned user roles in permissions, also it just made those url's not accessible. Please suggest what I am doing wrong, Thanks!

```
function my_module_permission() {
  $arr = array();
  $arr['access one_type_titles'] = array(
    'title' => t('Access First Type Titles'),
    'description' => t('Allow users to First Type Titles page.')
  );

  $arr['access second_type_titles'] = array(
    'title' => t('Access Second type Title page'),
    'description' => t('Allow users to access Second type Title page.')
  );

  return $arr;
}


function my_module_menu() {


  $items['type'] = array(

    'description' => t('Page for translation'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('custom_list'),
    'access arguments' => array('access one_type_titles content'),


  );

  $items['type/fr'] = array(
    'title' => t('French Links'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 1,
    'page arguments' => array('custom_list'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'access arguments' => array('access one_type_titles content'),
  );

  $items['type/en'] = array(
    'title' => t('English Links'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 2,
    'page arguments' => array('custom_list'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'access arguments' => array('access second_type_titles content'),



  );

  return $items;
}
```

Using `'access callback' => can_the_user_see_this_item,` and then coding access according to user role make it works but not with above method.

```
function can_the_user_see_this_item(){
 if (condition....) ) {
    return TRUE;
  }else{
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove 'content' word from 'access arguments' in hook_menu, because you custom permissions don't contain it. Clear cache.

```
'access arguments' => array('access one_type_titles'),
```

Comment: Thanks it works great now, that will be very helpful if you can little explain for what content word is used in permissions!

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a special meaning for 'content' word. You define new permissions in hook_permission and you should use them with the same names 'access one_type_titles' , 'access second_type_titles'